# how do i finish my tkinter in my program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I made a program which finds a factor of a number 
my problem is how do i print the name into the tkinter
i asked first the name of the user then ask what number and show the factor of that number
then the program asks the user if he wants to enter another one
the 0 means to exit
i wanted it once he types 0 to show a thank you in tkinter with his name
"Thank you! name for using my program!"

I'm fairly new to tkinter and i'm a pretty bad learner
i dont know how to write his name in tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

print("Finding Factors Program by Joshua Lozada")

name=input("what is your name?")
print ("Hello",name, " Welcome To My Finding factors Program")


def factor_finder(x): 
    print("The factors of",x,"are:")
    for i in range(1, x + 1):     
        if x % i == 0:
            print(i) 


while True:
    try:
        num = int(input("Enter an integer (0 to exit): "))
        if num == 0:
             window = Tk()
             window.title("Thank you!")
             window.configure(background="black")
             Label (window, bg="black") 
             Label(window, text = "Thank you for using my program!" , bg 
="black", fg="white", font= "none 12 bold") .grid(row=0, column=0, 
sticky=W)
             break
        factor_finder(num)
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, you must enter an integer")
```

i want the program once ended show
tkinter and show a thank you name for using my program!

Comment: It could just be when you uploaded your post, but there are a few indentation errors in your code. Additionally, the one thing you're missing is window.mainloop() Put it before your break and should get a message. This is also a  good resource when working with tkinter: https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-application-windows.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's what you need to do in order to print name along with the message on the tkinter window

```
Label(window, text = "Thank you "+name+" for using my program" , bg 
="black", fg="white", font= "none 12 bold") .grid(row=0, column=0, 
sticky=W)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put your `tkinter` code outside of the game loop; that is upon termination, the mainloop should exit (`break`), then execute the `tkinter` code:

Maybe like this?

```
import tkinter as tk

print("Finding Factors Program by Joshua Lozada")

name=input("what is your name?")
print ("Hello",name, " Welcome To My Finding factors Program")


def factor_finder(x): 
    print("The factors of",x,"are:")
    for i in range(1, x + 1):     
        if x % i == 0:
            print(i) 

while True:
    try:
        num = int(input("Enter an integer (0 to exit): "))
        if num == 0:
            break
        factor_finder(num)
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, you must enter an integer")

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Thank you!")
window.configure(background="black")
tk.Label(window, bg="black") 
tk.Label(window, text="Thank you for using my program!", bg="black", fg="white", font= "none 12 bold").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

window.mainloop()
```